# How wifi solve medium access (Distributed Co-ordination Function) in overlapped channels

Tags: ieee-802.11

My locality has 11 Access points and as per wifi specification only 11 channels are available which are overlapped. Assuming all 11 Access points working on these 11 overlapped channels (each at one channel). How the PCF and DCF function performed by clients of Access points or Access points itself. Do the clients and AP listen to all nearby channels or they work independently. If working independently, do the collision occur as the channels are overlapped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DO NOT use overlapping channels.  There are only three usable channels in the 2.4 GHz band:  **1,6, and 11.**  Use only these three.  If you use other channels, all your clients will interfere with each other and you will get very poor performance.

[This question and answers](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6938/is-it-safe-to-use-any-wifi-channel-in-the-2-4ghz-band) also explain why.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I gone through the link also. So does it mean that APs working at channel 1 and 2 will not wait for SIFS or DIFS time or set their backoff timer for each other.